# Bootstrap, less - make a box where height = width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm trying to get my head around less & bootstrap mixings. What I need is a box which will take 4 columns and have the same height.

```
.box-4x4 {
  .make-lg-column(4);
  height: ?
}
```

Is there any way to calculate it using LESS?

Answer (score 3):

Just look at [the definition](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.1.1/less/mixins.less#L746) of the `.make-lg-column` mixin and apply the same for the `height`, e.g.:

```
.box-4x4 {
    @columns: 4;
    .make-lg-column(@columns);
    @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
        height: percentage((@columns / @grid-columns));
    }
}
```